# Add description to category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently i'm a bit stuck at the category page.
I've created a page with the thumbnail and the category name. 
Now, i'dd like to add the description of the category above the title.

The description of the category is shown on the page to choose the product, but i just can't get it on the category page.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 category_layer" <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_subcategory hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_open - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );


/**
 * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_subcategory hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>
</div
```

I'll guess i miss something when i'd like to add:

```
<?php
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
?>
```

I tried to put it above:

```
@hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title -10
```

Is someone able to help me out? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to display the title ? The hooked method ?

Comment: Hi Mtxz thanx for responding. The hook i use is: 
  `* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title - 10`
It's in the content-product_cat.php file.

Comment: OK but what is the custom function you hooked? The one outputting the title

Comment: I think i don't understand what you mean to be honest. I tried to get the description with the use of these hookes and action: 
`/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );`

Comment: But you want to display the category description on the template right ? So you need to 1. find the correct hook to use in the template, 2. create a method in your function.php that returns/output the title, 3. attach this method to the template hook you choosed

Comment: Thanx Mtxz, 

1) The correct hook is `woocommerce_archive_description`
2) Guess that's a bit my problem at the moment, have to find out how to implement it on the right way.
3) i'm trying to attach it to the template content-product_cat.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', function($category){
    echo '<p>' . category_description($category->id) . '</p>';
} );
```

I'm not sure about the `$category->id`, please check the object type, you need category (term id) as `category_description()` parameter, or any other way here to output the term description from `$category` parameter.

Comment: Hi Mtxz, thanks for the suggestion, it's not working. I'll keep op trying today and maybe there are coming more suggestions in today ;-)

Comment: I'm almost there :-) 

`function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
 global $product;
 if ( ! $product->post->post_excerpt ) return;
 ?>
 <div itemprop="description">
  <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ) ?>
 </div>
 <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5);`

Is the function for adding it to the pages with the product, now trying to get it on the main /shop page.

Comment: Shop page or category page?

Comment: On the "main" shop page, i've set up the woocommerce in the way, people first choose the menu item "Shop". They choose the category, then shown all the products in that category.

Comment: Give me a example url please. Are you sure it's the shop page and not a taxonomy/category page?

Comment: Ah ok, so this is next to every category right ? Could you post the full code for your loop that display the 2 block at bottom ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177732/discussion-between-onno-v-and-mtxz).